# DataSourcesTableAdapters connection to SQLite

Tags: datatable, system.data.sqlite

For my VB.Net project I am trying to add support for a SQLite database.  I have installed the System.Data.SQLite.dll via NuGet and VS 2010.

I can successfully connect to the SQLite database and run some queries directly against it.  However, I am unable to load any data into my DataSourcesTableAdapters.  I get a "The 'System.Data.SQLite' provider is not registered on the local machine." error as soon as I try to fill the data table.

Everything works fine when I use my original MS Access data file.

Target CPU is x86

System.Data.SQLite.dll is copied to the local app folder

```
Stack Trace:
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbServicesWrapper.GetDataSource(constr As OleDbConnectionString, datasrcWrapper As DataSourceWrapper&)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(constr As OleDbConnectionString, connection As OleDbConnection)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(options As DbConnectionOptions, poolGroupProviderInfo As Object, pool As DbConnectionPool, owningObject As DbConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(owningConnection As DbConnection, poolGroup As DbConnectionPoolGroup)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(owningConnection As DbConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(outerConnection As DbConnection, connectionFactory As DbConnectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.QuietOpen(connection As IDbConnection, originalState As ConnectionState&)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(dataset As DataSet, datatables As DataTable[], startRecord As Int32, maxRecords As Int32, srcTable As String, command As IDbCommand, behavior As CommandBehavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(dataTables As DataTable[], startRecord As Int32, maxRecords As Int32, command As IDbCommand, behavior As CommandBehavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable As DataTable)
   at LisanoEnterprises.GrandPrix.DataSourcesTableAdapters.RostersTableAdapter.GetDataByRound(Round As Int32)
   at LisanoEnterprises.GrandPrix.ReportCtrl.ViewRosters(objReportCriteria As ReportCriteria)
   at LisanoEnterprises.GrandPrix.frmReports.ViewRoster()
   at LisanoEnterprises.GrandPrix.frmReports.ViewReport(iCategory As Int32, iReportNum As Int32)
   at LisanoEnterprises.GrandPrix.frmReports.btnMainView_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

Exception Hierarchy:
Top Level   System.InvalidOperationException    Void GetDataSource(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionString, System.Data.OleDb.DataSourceWrapper ByRef)
    The 'System.Data.SQLite' provider is not registered on the local machine.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to work around the issue. Instead of using the table adapters, I am loading a data table from a data reader.

```
  Dim reader As IDataReader = _dbCtrl.ExecuteReader(sSQL)
  Dim dt As New DataTable

  dt.Load(reader)

  reader.Close()
```